# Avoid sql injection in android app (Java for Android)

Tags: android-security

I've an android app that has been reported by the Google Play Store to be at risk of sql injection, the app was written in native code (Java for Android).
The problem is: the sql commands (to be exact it is Sqlite) are not sent directly by the code, but are sent by a library integrated into the project (it would be really difficult to modify the library).
So to avoid sql injection I thought of inserting in the various text fields in the app some mechanism to recognize the sql code eventually entered by users and, in this case, blocks the flow of the app generating an exception.
Do you know if there is something that could be useful for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad situation to be in, you could look into [OWASP SQLi Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for potential solutions but TBH exchanging the library might be the best way forward.